# php date time function

Tags: php, datetime

I want to convert this date ( 02-12-2010) mm-dd-yyyy to time format

ie

to 02-12-2010 0 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds

i have user time and date functions but when i refresh the page its value is changing as per the time.

i need that to be fixed

also i want to convert this date (01-24-2009) to time format.

please help me

Thanks

Comment: Why some intelligent people downvote beginner-level posts? Do they expect all questions to be at advanced level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) function to convert an existing date/time string into a timestamp for the [date](http://www.php.net/date) function.

```
$new_date = date('m-d-Y h:i:s', strtotime('02-12-2010'));
```

The reason that your date keeps updating with the current time is that the date() function uses the current system's timestamp by default when no second parameter is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use the date_parse_from_format () API function to transform your given format to an array. E.g.

```
$date = "02-12-2010";
$dateArr = date_parse_from_format("d-m-Y", $date);
```

Output it with something like:

```
$output = $dateArr['day'] . '-' . $dateArr['month'] '-' . $dateArr['year'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**strtotime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function eg:

```
$mydate = date('m-d-Y h:i:s', strtotime('02-12-2010'));
```